# How to change proxy api dynamically In ext js4?

Tags: api, extjs, proxy, extjs4

I am working in extjs4 using MVC structure and I want to **change my proxy setting of api**(create) to another url.I am getting stuck at this point.here is my some code

```
 Ext.define('Balaee.model.sn.UserModel',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        //idproperty:'userId',//fields property first position pk. 
        fields: ['userId','firstName','middleName','lastName','languageId','primaryEmail','birthDate','password','securityQuestionId','securityQuestionAnswer','isMale','creationTime','ipAddress','confirmationCode','userStatusId',],
        proxy:
        {
            type:'ajax',
            api:
            {
                read:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
                create:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=SocialNetworking/user/AuthenticateLogin',
                update:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=SocialNetworking/user/Registration'

            },//end of api
            reader:
            {
                type:'json',
            },//end of reader
            writer:
            {
                type:'json',
                root:'records',
            },//End of writer
        }//end of proxy
}
```

Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this with `Ext.apply` or `Ext.applyIf`.

```
var userModel = Ext.create('Balaee.model.sn.UserModel',{}),
    proxy = userModel.getProxy();

Ext.apply(proxy.api, {
    create  : '/controller/new',
    read    : '/controller/load',
    update  : '/controller/update',
    destroy : '/controller/destroy_action'
});
```

Comment: With applyIf you are not able to override. I recommend to use just apply so that you can change also already set properties. It is also possible to change the whole proxy cause I am not sure if this will work (even if it should work, at least for a url API)

Comment: You are right @sra ..again.. :) applyIf applies only if the config doesn't already exists.